# Java- Writing a search algorithm for 2d array that finds all paths by moving 1 step in any sorrounding tile

Tags: java, arrays, search, stack

I am trying to debug my class. This class is going through a boggle board and finding every available path. Paths include horizontal, vertical, and diagonal. You may not repeat a step. I currently have a lot of print statements trying to figure out where I am going wrong, but I can't seem to find it. I left these in. I think it has something to do with my currentPath[][]. Any pointers tips would be appreciated.

```
public class FindWords {
String [][] board;
final int LAST_LETTER = 2;
final int BEEN_THERE = 1;
final int AVAILABLE = 0;
BoggleDictionary Dictionary;

private StackADT<SearchWords> searchStack = new ArrayStack<SearchWords>();
public StackADT<SearchWords> foundStack = new ArrayStack<SearchWords>();

public FindWords (String [][] board) throws Exception {
    this.board = board;
    this.Dictionary = new BoggleDictionary();
    //this.foundStack = null;
}

public void startSearch(){


    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < board[0].length; j++){
            System.out.println(board[i][j]);
            String firstLetter = "";
            int [][] pathBoard = makeBlankBoard();

            pathBoard[i][j] = LAST_LETTER;

            System.out.println(">>" + Arrays.deepToString(pathBoard));
            firstLetter = board[i][j];
            System.out.println("first letters : " + firstLetter + " <====");
            SearchWords thisPath = new SearchWords(pathBoard, firstLetter);
            searchStack.push(thisPath);

        }
    }
    Search();
}

private boolean Search(){
    while (!searchStack.isEmpty())
    {

        SearchWords searchObj = searchStack.pop();
        int [][] currentPath = searchObj.getPath();

        int [][] array = new int [currentPath.length][currentPath[0].length];
        for (int i = 0; i <currentPath.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j <currentPath[0].length; j++){
                array[i][j] = currentPath[i][j];
            }
        }
        String makingString = searchObj.getString();


        if (makingString.length() > 2){
            if (Dictionary.contains(makingString)){
                foundStack.push(searchObj);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i ++){
            for (int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++){
                if (array[i][j] == LAST_LETTER){ //finding the last position in the string
                    int x = i;
                    int y = j;
                    //array[i][j] = BEEN_THERE;
                    pushPosition(searchObj, x+1, y+1, i, j); //lower left then going counter-clockwise
                    pushPosition(searchObj, x, y+1, i, j);
                    pushPosition(searchObj, x-1, y+1, i, j);
                    pushPosition(searchObj, x-1, y, i, j);
                    pushPosition(searchObj, x-1, y-1, i, j);
                    pushPosition(searchObj, x, y-1, i, j);
                    pushPosition(searchObj, x+1, y-1, i, j);
                    pushPosition(searchObj, x+1, y, i, j);

                }
            }
        }
    }

    return true;

}



private void pushPosition (SearchWords obj, int x, int y, int i, int j){
    int [][] currentPath = obj.getPath();
    String makingString = obj.getString();
    System.out.println("In push method: " + Arrays.deepToString(currentPath) +x+y+i+j);

    if (validPosition(x, y, currentPath)){

        currentPath[x][y] = LAST_LETTER;
        currentPath[i][j] = BEEN_THERE;

        System.out.println("after valid ch: "+ Arrays.deepToString(currentPath));

        makingString = makingString + board[x][y];
        SearchWords newPath = new SearchWords(currentPath, makingString);

        System.out.println("is string getting longer: " + makingString);
        System.out.println("Stack size: " + searchStack.size());


        System.out.println("pushing back on stack"+ Arrays.deepToString(currentPath));
        searchStack.push(newPath);
    }
}

private boolean validPosition (int x, int y, int [][] path){
    boolean result = false;

    if (x >= 0 && x < board.length && y >= 0 && y < board[x].length){
        if (path[x][y] == AVAILABLE){
            System.out.println("Checked position : " + x + y);
            result = true;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
private int [][] makeBlankBoard(){
    int row = board.length;
    int col = board[0].length;
    int [][] blankBoard = new int [row][col];

    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < board[0].length; j++){
            blankBoard[i][j] = AVAILABLE;

        }
    }
    return blankBoard;
}
```

}

UPDATED CLASS THAT WORKS. Needed to make a new copy of pathBoard before calling push method. Thanks killscreeen.

```
private void Search(){
    while (!searchStack.isEmpty())
    { 
        System.out.println("stack size in search: " + searchStack.size());

        SearchWords searchObj = searchStack.pop();
        int lastLetterRow = searchObj.getRow();
        int lastLetterCol = searchObj.getCol();
        String stringSoFar = searchObj.getString();
        int [][] pathBoard = searchObj.getPath();

        System.out.println ("row then Col: " + lastLetterRow + lastLetterCol);
        System.out.println ("string so far: " + stringSoFar);
        System.out.println("Path board so far in search: " + Arrays.deepToString(pathBoard)+ "\n");

        if (stringSoFar.length() > 2){
            if (Dictionary.contains(stringSoFar)){
            foundStack.push(searchObj);
            System.out.println("Found word!! " + stringSoFar);
        }
            }
        System.out.println("made it past if dict");

        //lower left then going counter-clockwise
        pushPosition (pathBoard, stringSoFar, lastLetterRow+1, lastLetterCol+1, lastLetterRow, lastLetterCol);
        pathBoard = makeCopy(pathBoard);
        pushPosition (pathBoard, stringSoFar, lastLetterRow, lastLetterCol+1, lastLetterRow, lastLetterCol);
        pathBoard = makeCopy(pathBoard);
        pushPosition(pathBoard, stringSoFar, lastLetterRow, lastLetterCol+1, lastLetterRow, lastLetterCol);
        pathBoard = makeCopy(pathBoard);
        pushPosition(pathBoard, stringSoFar, lastLetterRow-1, lastLetterCol+1, lastLetterRow, lastLetterCol);
        pathBoard = makeCopy(pathBoard);
        pushPosition(pathBoard, stringSoFar, lastLetterRow-1, lastLetterCol, lastLetterRow, lastLetterCol);
        pathBoard = makeCopy(pathBoard);
        pushPosition(pathBoard, stringSoFar, lastLetterRow-1, lastLetterCol-1, lastLetterRow, lastLetterCol);
        pathBoard = makeCopy(pathBoard);
        pushPosition(pathBoard, stringSoFar, lastLetterRow, lastLetterCol-1, lastLetterRow, lastLetterCol);
        pathBoard = makeCopy(pathBoard);
        pushPosition(pathBoard, stringSoFar, lastLetterRow+1, lastLetterCol-1, lastLetterRow, lastLetterCol);
        pathBoard = makeCopy(pathBoard);
        pushPosition(pathBoard, stringSoFar, lastLetterRow+1, lastLetterCol, lastLetterRow, lastLetterCol);

    }
    System.out.println("FOUND WORDS:");
    while(!foundStack.isEmpty()){
        SearchWords foundWords = foundStack.pop();
        System.out.println(foundWords.getString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give more insight on the expected behavior?

One bug I see is that you make a copy of your current path array every iteration in your `Search` method, but reuse this copy 8 times in subsequent `pushPosition` calls. This is why you see a lot of 2's (`LAST_LETTER`) in your `currentPath`

Comment: Yes. This is just a small 2x2 array. I am pushing each element as a starting position. Then my search should find all the valid moves (each element has 3) grab the letter at that position, update where it has been and where the last letter it has grabbed is, and push it back on the stack. Then I will pop again and do the same thing, until I have grabbed all paths. Does that help?

Comment: I think I see what you are saying, but I am not sure of the fix. should I make a copy before every pushPostion call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it looks like the specific trouble you're running into is that multiple paths are sharing the same array which describes the path that you have searched in. This creates bugs wherein their search histories overwrite each one another, leaving a not particularly useful set of information in the `currentPath` array.

Doing an array copy for each path that gets pushed would probably resolve this issue (there may be other issues in the code, but nothing pops out at me.)

I would advocate a different approach to storing the path array, as there's really no need to make copies of the whole grid every time. Instead, you could track each path as:

- The location of the last letter in the path (useful for taking the next step in the path, as in your algorithm)
- The previous path leading up to that point (which would be an object of the same type

Code sample would look like (note that I haven't tested this, as it's intended only as an example):

```
class SearchPath {
    int x, y;
    String string;
    SearchPath prior;

    // x,y are most recent position; prior is the path up to this point, or null
    public SearchPath(int x, int y, String board, SearchPath prior) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.string = (prior != null ? prior.string : "") + board[x][y];
        this.prior = prior;
    }

    // To check if an x,y location collides with this path
    public contains(int x, int y) {
        if (this.x == x && this.y == y) {
            return true;
        } else if (prior == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return prior.contains(x,y);
        }
    }
}
```

In your initial loop (`startSearch`) you would be pushing objects with no prior path (`new SearchPath(i, j, board, null)`). In your `search` loop, you would pop one of these and then push a `new SearchPath(searchPath.x - 1, searchPath.y, board, searchPath)` after checking that the new x/y coordinates haven't been used via the `contains` method. (Note that the use of a stack to store search paths probably isn't necessary either, as you should get the same search pattern just by making a recursive search call.)

Comment: Thank you. I like this, but while I was waiting I took your initial comment and decided gut most of my class and restart. I made a new method that made an exact copy of the array before I called my push method. And... it works!! Thank you for your help. I see now how I was using the same pathBoard. I am going to mark your answer as correct (I haven't tested either, but it looks like it should) I will also post my changes below for any viewers.